# Convert (bake ? ) cycles shaders to vertex colors for 3D printing

Tags: vertex-colors

Is there any solution to "bake" vertexcolors from cycles shaders, such as  voronoi, cells, pointiness etc...?
I want to make some colorful patterns by mixing shaders on objects via cycles and then print them on a 3D printer, for example this colorful icosphere:

[image: example]

(Blender 2.76b is running on my laptop)
Is this possible or not?

Comment: Oliver, what do you mean by "3D printing"? When I did a search of images using the parameters "multi color 3d printing", it did not appear to me from the images I saw that what you want to print is possible using consumer grade 3D hardware, though my experience in this field is limited, and there may be higher end hardware marketed to commercial markets of which I am unaware.

Comment: http://www.shapeways.com/materials/full-color-sandstone

for example